# Duplicate Items showing during Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

We are working on to upgrade Sitecore 9.0.2 to 10.3. We are getting some weird issue while installing any package 10.3 instance. After installing any packages there are multiple entries getting appearing i.e.

**Duplicate items after installing Packages.**

[image]

**Some of default items which Sitecore provide out of the box also having duplicate entries. Even after executing Step 2**
[image]

**Steps already executed.**

1. Ran the upgraded script on Core, Master, and Web DB.
2. Followed the steps as recommended in the Below Article as suggested by Himmat Singh Dulawat but nothing works
   [https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32616/duplicate-content-items-appearing-during-sitecore-upgrade-to-10-2]
3. Whenever we try to run the Cleanup database from control panel, it will remove the items which are created while installing the package.

Comment: The setting name `AllowDuplicateItemNamesOnSameLevel` in `Sitecore.config` file under the `App_Config` folder. Ensure is set to `false` to restrict the duplication while installing a package.

Comment: Please try rebuilding the Sitecore Master Index once.