# Duplicate related items in Links under Navigate after Sitecore upgrade to 10.2

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, upgrade, links

Upgraded an application on `Sitecore XM` from version 9 to 10.2.1. I installed `Sitecore CM\CD` via `SIF` and performed the `clean-up of databases` as per the [SC-XP-10.2.0-Upgrade-Guide-en](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102.aspx) under section 3.1.3.

The issue is duplicate linked items are showing up when clicking on the `links button` under the `Navigate` tab in the `Content Editor`.
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: See if it can help you: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32616/duplicate-content-items-appearing-during-sitecore-upgrade-to-10-2/32618#32618

Comment: Try to re-index your master index, this should help

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat I did the exact same thing as part of the clean-up of databases. But no luck.

Comment: rebuild your link db